# Debian wheezy and Ogre tutorial

Tags: debian, ogre, ogre3d

I'm trying to build [the first ogre tutorial](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Basic%20Tutorial%201&structure=Tutorials)

I'm on **Debian Wheezy - beta 4** and I've installed these packages :

- libois-dev
- libogre-dev

I've built the tutorial with this line :

```
g++ -I/usr/include/OGRE -I/usr/include/OIS -lOgreMain -lOIS -o main *.cpp
```

I get this : ***SdkTrays.h no such file or directory***

I've checked, the header is neither in /usr/include or in /usr/local/include (recursively).

Is it possible to get sdktrays under debian squeeze ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All the code from the Samples was removed from Debian because it contains a lot of unknown, non-DFSG-free content, as explained in [Debian Bug #684218](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=684218).  After a [discussion with the OGRE maintainers about it](http://ogre3d.org/mantis/view.php?id=546), the Debian maintainers decided to just remove all of the Samples directory, which breaks the tutorial because they lean on the samples a lot for some early simple GUI stuff and models.

All the versions before 1.7.4+dfsg1-6 have the samples included.  Here's how to build it from the source repository:

1. Clone the debian source repository from `http://anonscm.debian.org/git/pkg-games/ogre.git`
2. Check out the last version of the debian packaging which included the Samples - `git co debian/1.7.4-5`
3. Build the package (unsigned) - `git-buildpackage -us -uc -rfakeroot --git-ignore-branch`
4. Install your packages using `dpkg -i` in the directory above this one.  You probably want to use either the normal or -dbg versions of the libraries, and not all of them.
5. You can now compile the tutorial applications.

Eventually you will move away from the sample framework which is used in the samples and you can replace this old version with the official Debian one.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a look at the available packages and even the 1.8 versions do for some reason not include OgreBites (to which SdkTrays belongs).

As a result your only option is to [build Ogre from source](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Building+Ogre) and grab the code yourself from the [official Ogre BitBucket repository](https://bitbucket.org/sinbad/ogre/).